# Get and print selected item in DropDownList ASP.NET MVC as an h3 header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Trying to print the selected file type as an header 3 to make sure it is passing into the next model. I was hoping it wold be activated after the submit button in the view but nothing comes up.  I've got it working with a text box but cant seem to understand how to access it with a drop down list.

I am using Httpget and httppost and it doesn't seem to work.

**Model**

```
namespace FindFileStringFinal.Models
{
    public class FileTypeModel
    {
        public string SelectedType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Type { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var fileType = new FileTypeModel();

            fileType.Type = new[]
            {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Xml", Selected=true },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Html" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Css" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "C#" }

            };


            return View(fileType);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FileTypeModel fileType)
        {

           var dir = new DirectoryModel();
           **dir.Type = fileType.SelectedType;**
           return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
@model FindFileStringFinal.Models.FileTypeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h3>File Type</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Find", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedType,new SelectList(Model.Type, "Value", "Text"),
                "Select a File Type",  new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Find", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <h3>Selected: @Model.SelectedType</h3>
                    <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-default" />


                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Find Directory", "About")
</div>
```

I have this exact same code for two textboxs with the same input button and it prints out as a header 3 so it shows me that the information is being stored.
 Why is it not working this the dropboxlist? I also put httppost inside of get because I only need to receive the information in that part and nothing else.

I don't know if that is good or bad practice because I could barely find httpget and httppost tutorials that focus primarily on how it works or doesn't work inside  the view.

Any feedback would be helpful since this is my first time working with MVC.

Comment: Using `new SelectList()` in the view is pointless extra overhead - it just creates another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedType, Model.Type, ....)`

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and not supported, and any case the 2nd form has no form controls so would never post back anything. All you are doing is making a GET which does not have a parameter for your model (or `SelectedType`), and all you ever do is return a new instance of `FileTypeModel `

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenMuecke ! I actually ended up reading your first comment on another MVC thread about new SelectList() <!-- language: c# -->and changed it after posting.
And thank you I was wondering if the nested forms overran each other. I couldn't find any reference that helped explain that for me. 
One more question... Where would be appropriate to start the HTTPGET form? Can I run the controller without it? and will it still run the HTTPGET version of my index page if the form doesn't exist in the view?